# VBA download won't finish until all code runs

Tags: excel, vba

This will be a little vague as i cannot provide all the relevant information needed, but maybe someone is up for the challenge.

I am trying to download an excel file from a website and then save that excel file. Here is my code.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "####"

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.document.getElementById("###").Click

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Application.SendKeys "%{o}"

Set ie = Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "####"

End Sub
```

The code works when I don't include anything after the sendkeys. If I include any code after the sendkeys the download will wait to download until after that code has been run. I tried using

```
Application.Wait Not + TimeValue("xx:xx:xx")
```

but that only served to pause the download as well. Is there any kind of loop that I can run similar to ie readystate loop listed below?

```
Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Or another trick to finish the download before continuing the rest of my macro?